# Binding Odata to a KendoUI datasource for use with Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, odata

I am trying to bind a kendo datasource to a odata source for the first time without to much luck. I found an example product that allows versioning of the odata controller which looks pretty useful. The odata output looks something like

```
{
"d": {
    "__metadata": {
        "id": "http://localhost:11232/versionbyroute/v1/Products(7)",
        "uri": "http://localhost:11232/versionbyroute/v1/Products(7)",
        "type": "ODataVersioningSample.V1.ViewModels.Product",
        "actions": {
            "http://localhost:11232/versionbyroute/v1/$metadata#Container.Product": [
                {
                    "title": "Product",
                    "target": "http://localhost:11232/versionbyroute/v1/Products(7)/Product"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "ID": 7,
    "Name": "MS-DOS 3.0 (OEM)",
    "ReleaseDate": null,
    "SupportedUntil": null
}
```

}

Now with Kendo I am not quite sure how I am meant to gain access to ID & Name so far

```
   var datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: {
                beforeSend: function (req) {
                    req.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose');
                },
                url: "http://localhost:11232/versionbyroute/v1/Products(7)",

            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    Name: { type: "string" }

                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 20,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true
    });


    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        height: 430,
        sortable: true,
        dataSource: datasource,
        columns: [{ field: 'Name', title: 'Name' }]


    });
```

I feel I am close but I think I am doing something wrong with the way I setup the schema? Can anyone point me in the right direction.

EDIT

If anyone else is in the same boat

```
   $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        height: 430,
        sortable: true,
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    beforeSend: function (req) {
                                    req.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose');
                                },
                    url: "http://localhost:11232/versionbyroute/v1/Products",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            pageSize: 20,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true,
        },
        filterable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [{ field: 'Name', title: 'Name' }]
    });
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, it's best to answer your own question by actually using the "post your answer" section below (i.e. not editing your question with the answer). This way it is no longer listed as unanswered. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Answered by the author:

If anyone else is in the same boat

```
   $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        height: 430,
        sortable: true,
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    beforeSend: function (req) {
                                    req.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose');
                                },
                    url: "http://localhost:11232/versionbyroute/v1/Products",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            pageSize: 20,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true,
        },
        filterable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [{ field: 'Name', title: 'Name' }]
    });
```

Comment: This helped me. Actually it would be better if you'd explained the solution, but it worked as a drop in, so... Thanks!